# Do Characters lose skill ranks if their Intelligence score is drained below their base score?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, ability-scores, skills

Some creatures in Pathfinder can drain Intelligence, and this causes a permanent decrease that only a Restoration spell can undo. The Ability Scores page explains what happens in case of ability damage (temporary decrease) but not what happens in case of a drain.

Then can a Character (PC or NPC) lose some skill ranks when hit by an Intelligence drain (or does it do the same thing as ability damage) ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the **Ability Drain** on the bottom of the [Ability Scores](http://paizo.com/prd/glossary.html#ability-score-damage-penalty-and-drain) page of SRD:

> **Ability Drain**
>
> Ability drain actually reduces the relevant ability score. Modify all skills and statistics related to that ability. This might cause you to **lose skill points**, hit points, and other bonuses. Ability drain can be healed through the use of spells such as restoration.

Comment: What controls which skills are affected?

Comment: The GM, would be my guess.

Comment: ""You suffer from a suddenly memory loss..."

Comment: @Random832 The player controls it, just like they controlled which skills to learn in the first place.